# R Highcharter: Formatting tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a "stacked bar" chart and I put it against a wider bar to see if it fits in my criteria or not. I have the graph looking the way I want due to a trick (using `grouping = FALSE` and having the total of each column be the sum of the ones in front of it). The issue now is that the `tooltip` is showing incorrect numbers (correctly).

Question: Is there a way I can either format the tooltip to show what should be correct numbers (with color dot included) or create the graph in a different way?

[image]

For example, the picture shows the incorrect numbers on the `tooltip`, I want it to display:

- DIH Goal: 21hrs
- Quote Hold Time: 6.2hrs
- Other Hold Time: 19.3hrs
- Shop Time: 3.4 hrs

Code:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN2, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = 21), name = "DIH Goal", color = "#ffffff", borderColor = "#C8C8C8", pointPadding = -0.1) %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN2, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = round(HoldTime.Quote,1)), name = "Quote Hold Time", color = "#FF8888") %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN2, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = round(Hold.Time.Other,1)), name = "Other Hold Time", color = "#E5A919") %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN2, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = round(Shop.Time,1)), name = "Shop Time", color = "#51C1BC") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = "hours", labels = list(format = "{value}hrs")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, shared = TRUE, headerFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>", valueSuffix = "hrs") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(grouping = FALSE))
```

Data:

```
> dput(TopPN2)
structure(list(Incoming.P.N = c("PN1", "PN2", "PN3", "PN4", "PN5", 
"PN6", "PN7", "PN8", "PN9", "PN10"), HoldTime.Quote = structure(c(28.8846153846154, 
32.548, 21.8717948717949, 57.4931506849315, 64.4074074074074, 
40.0833333333333, 14, 29.680790960452, 36.6506024096386, 48.1111111111111
), class = "difftime", units = "days"), Hold.Time.Other = structure(c(22.7307692307692, 
21.56, 16.7435897435897, 10.7123287671233, 47.1851851851852, 
23.1666666666667, 6, 8.17231638418079, 25.1807228915663, 24.6666666666667
), class = "difftime", units = "days"), Shop.Time = c(3.40698998178506, 
4.83416980342953, 3.33075767332046, 4.39068799583821, 5.35449386300647, 
5.20028749401054, 3.43263196751569, 5.59119496855346, 4.27753861737149, 
5.61884753901561), Quantity = c(17568, 9564, 9318, 7689, 7577, 
6261, 5418, 5088, 3949, 3332)), .Names = c("Incoming.P.N", "HoldTime.Quote", 
"Hold.Time.Other", "Shop.Time", "Quantity"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

***UPDATE***

Going down the path of just formatting the `tooltip`. I have created new variables to represent the correct times but I cannot figure out how to input the correct color dots in the `tooltip`. The example found here: [How to use the tooltip formatter and still display chart color (like it does by default)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547184/how-to-use-the-tooltip-formatter-and-still-display-chart-color-like-it-does-by) shows how to do it in JS but I can't figure it out in R. My issue is I don't know how to use the double quotations between `color span` to make it pick up the correct color.

Updated Data:

```
> dput(TopPN2)
structure(list(Incoming.P.N = c("PN1", "PN2", "PN3", "PN4", "PN5", 
"PN6", "PN7", "PN8", "PN9", "PN10"), Hold.Time.Quote = structure(c(28.8846153846154, 
32.548, 21.8717948717949, 57.4931506849315, 64.4074074074074, 
40.0833333333333, 14, 29.680790960452, 36.6506024096386, 48.1111111111111
), class = "difftime", units = "days"), Hold.Time.Other = structure(c(22.7307692307692, 
21.56, 16.7435897435897, 10.7123287671233, 47.1851851851852, 
23.1666666666667, 6, 8.17231638418079, 25.1807228915663, 24.6666666666667
), class = "difftime", units = "days"), Shop.Time = c(3.40528709494031, 
4.83058282849384, 3.33075767332046, 4.38978424746556, 5.35178594965072, 
5.19380460683082, 3.43263196751569, 5.59119496855346, 4.27753861737149, 
5.61884753901561), Quantity = c(17590, 9574, 9318, 7694, 7587, 
6295, 5418, 5088, 3949, 3332), HoldTimeQuoteTrue = structure(c(6.2, 
11, 5.1, 46.8, 17.2, 16.9, 8, 21.5, 11.5, 23.4), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    HoldTimeOtherTrue = structure(c(18.8, 16.8, 13.7, 5.7, 38.6, 
    15.3, 0, 1.9, 20, 15.4), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    ShopTimeTrue = c(3.4, 4.8, 3.3, 4.4, 5.4, 5.2, 3.4, 5.6, 
    4.3, 5.6)), .Names = c("Incoming.P.N", "Hold.Time.Quote", 
"Hold.Time.Other", "Shop.Time", "Quantity", "HoldTimeQuoteTrue", 
"HoldTimeOtherTrue", "ShopTimeTrue"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Updated Code:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = 21), name = "DIH Goal", color = "#ffffff", borderColor = "#C8C8C8", borderWidth = 2, pointPadding = -0.1, 
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "DIH Goal: 21 days<br>")) %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = round(Hold.Time.Quote,1)), name = "Quote Hold Time", color = "#FF8888", 
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "<span style='color:{point.color}'>\u25CF</span> Quote Hold Time: {point.HoldTimeQuoteTrue} days<br>")) %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = round(Hold.Time.Other,1)), name = "Other Hold Time", color = "#E5A919", 
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.color} Other Hold Time: {point.HoldTimeOtherTrue} days<br>")) %>%
  hc_add_series(TopPN, "column", hcaes(x = Incoming.P.N, y = round(Shop.Time,1)), name = "Shop Time", color = "#51C1BC", 
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "Shop Time: {point.ShopTimeTrue} days<br>Volume: {point.Quantity}")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = "days", labels = list(format = "{value} days")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, shared = TRUE, 
             headerFormat = "<b>PN {point.key}</b><br>"
             ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(grouping = FALSE, events = list(click = ClickFunctionCustReviewPN)))
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `stacking: 'normal'` option?: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.stacking I suppose that stacked bars will represent your data better than columns with disabled grouping.

Comment: `stacking: 'normal'` works if I didn't have the column in the back that is wider than the others. Not sure how to do have 3 stacked columns and 1 non....

Comment: Put `stacking: 'normal'` only in the options of the series that you wish to stack: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgzu3f9d/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using your trick of a grouped column, have you considered using a plot line to illustrate your goal and how it relates to your data? Since your goal data is consistent, this could be a more readable indicator. And, since it's not a series in your chart, it wouldn't interfere with your tooltip.

Here's a modification of the Highcharts stacked column chart demo with a sample plot line: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/v3e7gouz/

```
yAxis: {
    ...
    plotLines: [{ 
        color: 'red', 
        value: 5, // the value on the y-axis were you want the line to appear
        width: 2, 
        zIndex: 1 // set this value to have the line appear above the y-axis gridline but below the column bars
    }],
    ...
}
```

[image]

I hope this is helpful for you.